# simple asp.net login page

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-4.0, authentication

I needed to create a simple fast login form for an internal company project I'm working on.  I saw [this tut](http://www.codefixer.com/asp-net/tutorials/password-protected-asp-net-login.asp) on how to do it using vb - looked really fast and easy. I ran it through a converter to change it to C# but when I load the page, this is the error I get:

```
CS0103: The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context
```

With the following code:

```
<script runat="server">
    public void Login(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbUserName.Text == "admin" & tbPassword.Text == "admin")
        {
            Session("Admin") = true;
            Response.Redirect("Dashboard.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Session("Admin") = false;
            litLogin.Visible = true;
            litLogin.Text = "<p>Sorry you have provided incorrect login details.</p>";

        }
    }
</script>
```

EDIT Adding brackets helps on the login page, but on the page im trying to protect you have to check for the session like this:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Admin"] != true)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
    }

</script>
```

And it throws `CS0019: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, you need to use `[`and `]` for indexers.

In other words, replace

```
Session("Admin")
```

With

```
Session["Admin"]
```

*In response to your edit*:

```
if (Session["Admin"] != true)
```

Should be cast to bool, so you should try:

```
if (!(bool)Session["Admin"])
```

(No need to compare a boolean value with true/false)

Comment: @tking, you might need to cast the retrieved session object to bool in order to make the comparison in C#. C# is a bit more strict about types. On another note, for "a simple and fast" login page for ASP .NET, have a look at the Login control and see if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, the last edit worked.  Next time I will just use the logincontrol.  Still getting into learning ASP.NET and wasn't aware it existed.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing:

```
Session("Admin")
```

with:

```
Session["Admin"]
```

In C#, brackets are used to access [indexed properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464.aspx), otherwise it looks like a method call and the compiler is complaining that there is no method called `Session`.

On the page which checks the session you need to cast to boolean because `Session["Admin"]` returns an object which is not comparable to the boolean value `true`:

```
if (!(bool)Session["Admin"])
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that throws a new one CS1525: Invalid expression term '!='     I'm starting to think forms auth would have been easier...

Comment: You missed the `!= true` part.